# Blazor WASM Load and display large pdfs by splitting them as streams

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, blazor-webassembly

I'm working on a Blazor WASM App and I want my users to easily open pdf files on specific pages that contain additional information.
I cannot distribute those files myself or upload them to any kind of server. Each user has to provide them themselves.

Because the files are up to 60MB big I cannot convert the uploaded file to base64 and display them as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17562800/14606084).

However I don't have to display the whole file and could just load the needed page +- some pages around them.

For that I tried using iText7 `ExtractPageRange()`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46377309/14606084) answer indicates, that I have to override the `GetNextPdfWriter()` Method and to store all streams in an collection.

```
class ByteArrayPdfSplitter : PdfSplitter {
public ByteArrayPdfSplitter(PdfDocument pdfDocument) : base(pdfDocument) {
}

protected override PdfWriter GetNextPdfWriter(PageRange documentPageRange) {
    CurrentMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    UsedStreams.Add(CurrentMemoryStream);
    return new PdfWriter(CurrentMemoryStream);
}

public MemoryStream CurrentMemoryStream { get; private set; }

public List<MemoryStream> UsedStreams { get; set; } = new List<MemoryStream>();
```

Then I thought I could merge those streams and convert them to base64

```
var file = loadedFiles.First();

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var rs = file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize);
        

        await rs.CopyToAsync(ms);

        ms.Position = 0;

        //rs needed to be converted to ms, because the PdfReader constructer uses a 
        //synchronious read that isn't supported by rs and throws an exception.
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(ms);
        
        var document = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
        var splitter = new ByteArrayPdfSplitter(document);
        
        var range = new PageRange();
        range.AddPageSequence(1, 10);
        
        var splitDoc = splitter.ExtractPageRange(range);

        //Edit commented this out, shouldn't have been here at all leads to an exception
        //splitDoc.Close();

        var outputMs = new MemoryStream();

        foreach (var usedMs in splitter.UsedStreams)
        {
            usedMs.Position = 0;
            outputMs.Position = outputMs.Length;
            await usedMs.CopyToAsync(outputMs);
        }
        
        var data = outputMs.ToArray();
        
        currentPdfContent = "data:application/pdf;base64,";
        currentPdfContent += Convert.ToBase64String(data);
        pdfLoaded = true;
    }
```

This however doesn't work.
Has anyone a suggestion how to get this working? Or maybe a simpler solution I could try.

---

Edit:

I took a closer look in debug and it seems like, the resulting stream `outputMs` is always empty. So it is probably a problem in how I split the pdf.

Comment: Which stream are you referring to exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After at least partially clearing up my misconception of what it means to not being able to access the file system from blazor WASM I managed to find a working solution.

```cs
        await using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        var rs = file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize);

        await using var fs = new FileStream("test.pdf", FileMode.Create)
                
        fs.Position = 0;

        await rs.CopyToAsync(fs);
        fs.Close();
            
        string path = "test.pdf";
        string range = "10 - 15";
        var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("test.pdf"));
        var split = new MySplitter(pdfDocument);
        var result = split.ExtractPageRange(new PageRange(range));
        result.Close();


        await using var splitFs = new FileStream("split.pdf", FileMode.Open))
        await splitFs.CopyToAsync(ms);

        var data = ms.ToArray();
            
        var pdfContent = "data:application/pdf;base64,";
        pdfContent += System.Convert.ToBase64String(data);
        Console.WriteLine(pdfContent);

        currentPdfContent = pdfContent;
```

With the MySplitter Class from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62219452/14606084) answer.

```cs
    class MySplitter : PdfSplitter
    {
        public MySplitter(PdfDocument pdfDocument) : base(pdfDocument)
        {
        }

        protected override PdfWriter GetNextPdfWriter(PageRange documentPageRange)
        {
            String toFile = "split.pdf";
            return new PdfWriter(toFile);
        }
    }
```